# Need to return instantaneous coordinates of x,y from moving object

Tags: matlab, coordinate-systems

The codes below given by Luis Mendo have been modified to allow multiple objects seen moving at once. I need to return the instantaneous x,y coordinate values for each n_step.  Pls help.

```
xmin=minServiceRange;
xmax=maxServiceRange;
randnum=xmin+rand(1,NoOfUsers)*(xmax-xmin);
xmin1=xmin;
xmax1=xmax;

NearestMBSt=zeros(1,NoOfUsers);
for i=1:NoOfUsers
r=0.015; 
v=linspace(0,2*pi) %circumference of object dot
origin_x{i} = userlocx(i)+ r*cos(v);
origin_y{i}  = userlocy(i)+ r*sin(v);
destination_x{i}  = origin_x{i} + 1;
destination_y{i} = origin_y{i} + 1;
end

n_steps = 10; % granulity of image
t_pause = 1; % seconds between frames, movement speed

for i=1:NoOfUsers
h(i)= fill(origin_x{i}, origin_y{i}, 'ro');%create image of users
hold on
end
axis([0 maxServiceRange 0 maxServiceRange])
axis equal
axis manual
for t = linspace(0,1,n_steps)
    for i=1:NoOfUsers

    x{i} = (1-t)*origin_x{i} + t*destination_x{i};
    y{i} = (1-t)*origin_y{i} + t*destination_y{i};
    set(h(i), 'Vertices', [x{i}(:) y{i}(:)])
    instlocorix=cell2mat(origin_x);
    instlocoriy=cell2mat(origin_y);
    instlocdestx=cell2mat(destination_x);
    instlocdesty=cell2mat(destination_y);


    end
    pause(t_pause)
    drawnow
end
```